# Return-Oriented Programming: Are all the code sequences ended with “ret” potential “gadgets” for ROP attack?

Tags: assembly, exploit

So by reading this rop [paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/rop.pdf) from Dr. Shacham, I know that it is not very hard to find gadgets set that has Turning-complete computation ability.

So I am thinking that, in theoretical, are all the asm code sequences ended with **ret** can be used as gadgets in ROP attack?

Is it wrong? Could anyone give me some counteract example?

Comment: `hlt`,`ret` sequence wouldn't be very useful for you :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff aha! an extreme but acceptable example:) But do they really be used in gcc generated asm code?

Comment: Maybe not as intended instructions, but you are not limited by original instruction boundaries. `hlt; ret` would be just a 2 byte sequence of `F4 C3` which can turn up by accident in some other instruction. For example `jmp .-15367` is `E9 F4 C3 FF FF`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, yes all commands that end with an ret instruction can be used as gadgets.
But there arises cases where the gadgets that you search for end with a call rather than an ret.

But then again, anything that ends with ret cant be used as effective gadgets.

For example 'nop;ret' is the most useless gadget that I can think of.
I don't think you can use that as a useful gadget, but it is a gadget nevertheless.